# ¿Por qué se usa el subjunctivo cuando la frase empieza con "Eso explica que"?

Tags: subjuntivo

Contexto: Está hablando sobre los volcanes cercanos y el peligro inmenente.

> Eso explica que mi abuela chilena **espere** siempre lo peor, **esté**
>   preparada para emergencias y **ande** por la vida con un sano fatalismo,
>   apoyada por algunos santos católicos de su preferencia y por los vagos
>   consejos del horóscopo.

No cabe duda que no cabe duda aquí. ¿Por qué el subjunctivo?

Comment: Si imaginas "Propongo que fulana *haga* tal cosa" está claro que se use el subjuntivo, ¿no?  De ahí es un pequeño salto a "Eso explica por que fulana *haga* tal  cosa."

Comment: Pero "propongo" delimita una circunstancia donde alguien quiere influir otra persona, mientras que "explica" no involucra un deseo de influir. Las reglas en juega son differente.

Comment: Es un poco como "That explains that my Chilean grandmother *would* [*might*] always expect the worst."  "Would" y "might" se expresan con el subjuntivo porque no hay certeza.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En un viejo hilo de un foro encuentro precisamente [esta pregunta](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/explicar-indicativo-subjuntivo.2771446/?hl=es). Las respuestas que se dan provienen de la *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española* (NGLE).

En muy pocas palabras, *explicar* aquí tiene valor de *justificar*, y las subordinadas encabezadas por este verbo y otros similares van en subjuntivo.

Más abajo la explicación completa del razonamiento.

En la NGLE por un lado se constata el hecho de que *explicar* pueda disparar un uso de subjuntivo en una subordinada:

> NGLE, §25.4q «[...] *explicar*, *garantizar* y otros verbos similares
>   se construyen con complementos en indicativo. [...] sin embargo, que
>   cuando presentan sujetos no personales suelen utilizarse en
>   subjuntivo, con lo que se obtienen contrastes como *El maestro te ha
>   explicado que las cosas no son como tú pensabas*, con indicativo ~
>   *Eso explica que las cosas no sean como tú piensas*, con subjuntivo.»

Más adelante se vuelve a recurrir a la NGLE (el resaltado es mío):

> §25.3ñ «Eligen también el subjuntivo los predicados que denotan CAUSA
>   de algo. Entre los sustantivos cabe señalar *causa, culpa,
>   **explicación**, justificación, motivo, origen, razón*…»

y finalmente, volviendo al primer apartado:

> Nótese que los dos usos de *explicar* que se han mostrado coinciden en
>   tener el significado de 'presentar explicaciones', por lo que no
>   parece que la alternancia constituya exactamente un caso de homonimia.
>   No obstante, solo en uno de ellos se asimila este verbo a los
>   predicados de lengua o de comunicación mencionados antes. Se vio en
>   los **25.3ñ,o** que los que introducen la causa o la razón de algo
>   (*justificar*, *probar*, etc.) se construyen en subjuntivo. **Cabe
>   entender, por tanto, que el deslizamiento de una noción a la otra
>   (aproximadamente, ASERCIÓN --> JUSTIFICACIÓN) pueda tener alguna
>   influencia en el cambio de modo que ponen de manifiesto estos
>   predicados.**

Pasando en limpio: el subjuntivo se utiliza para expresar justificaciones o razones, y no es difícil extender esa idea a la de explicación. Las siguientes frases son después de todo equivalentes:

- *Ésa es la causa de que mi abuela chilena espere siempre lo peor.*
- *Eso justifica que mi abuela chilena espere siempre lo peor.*
- *Ésa es la razón de que mi abuela chilena espere siempre lo peor.*
- *Eso explica que mi abuela chilena espere siempre lo peor.*

Aquí podríamos preguntarnos por qué se usa el subjuntivo en todos estos casos, pero en realidad allí ya entramos en un terreno más difícil. Hay construcciones que sintácticamente hacen obligatorio el subjuntivo y no tiene sentido preguntarse por qué. Pero que exista un patrón bastante consistente de uso del subjuntivo en subordinadas que expresan causa o justificación es una especie de explicación: lo que vemos como una anomalía es en realidad una regla que se extiende a muchos otros verbos y predicados, y que toca a *explicar* cuando tiene la connotación de *justificar*.

Buscando fuentes para esto me crucé con varios ensayos sobre la enseñanza del subjuntivo a personas de otras lenguas, como el inglés, que no tienen este modo verbal, y los mismos coinciden en que enseñarlo como básicamente "el modo de lo irreal o hipotético" suele frustrar a los alumnos.

Con respecto a eso, y a riesgo de motivar otra pregunta más, en ningún lado queda más claro que el subjuntivo no es "el modo de lo hipotético" que en su uso (alternando con el indicativo) en la frase *el hecho de que*.

Comment: Es interesante. Parece que aquí se usa así el subjunctivo con sujetos no humanos pero a lo mejor porque en estos casos es esperado que la información será evaluada emocionalmente. En definitiva, he recogida que "el hecho de que" se usa con subjunctivo cuando algo es presentado para su valoración emocional que todavía se conoce versus algo desconocido presentado para informar.

Comment: En cambio, *Ésa es la razón/causa por la que mi abuela chilena espera siempre lo peor* y *Eso explica por qué mi abuela chilena espera siempre lo peor*