# ¿Por qué se usa subjuntivo aquí: "Decir o pedir algo con tanta insistencia que *resulte* molesto o impertinente"?

Tags: subjuntivo

Solo puedo encontrar la [regla](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tanto-que-subjunctive.2008643/) cuando el caso indica expectación o cuando expresa el negativo y ningún de los dos aplica aquí:

> dar la barrila: Decir o pedir algo con tanta insistencia que **resulte**
>   molesto o impertinente.

Comment: No sé explicar por qué se usa el subjuntivo en esa frase pero no solo se utiliza en los dos supuestos que indicas en tu pregunta, pongo un enlace con más información sobre el uso del subjuntivo: http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Subjuntivo

Comment: @walen no es una  expressión impersonal

Comment: @walen, esto puede emplicarlo (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20993/por-qu%C3%A9-se-usa-el-subjunctivo-cuando-la-frase-empieza-con-eso-explica-que) pero la forma es algo diferente.

Comment: @walen I'll accept that as a duplicate

Comment: @walen I have a vague memory of a rule when you say something is very much something or the most of something that it is followed by the subjunctive but I'm not positive and I can't remember what that superlative type expression is called so I'll take an answer that is more familiar and I know for sure is from spanish.